# connect PyQT5 signal from service class to multiple slots

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots

I build a (singleton) service class including a "something_changed"-signal. This service is included in a base parent class and therein connected to a slot. From this parent class, two child classes are derived Child1 and Child2, both initialized in the main method.

When I send the signal, only the slot of the last connected child is executed, it seems, that only one connection is possible (in contrast to the docs and other source e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36297069/9614490)).

To demonstrate my problem, I simplified the classes:

**Service.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal

class Service(QObject):
    __instance = None

    something_changed = pyqtSignal()

    def __new__(cls) -> "Service":
        if cls.__instance is None:
            print("Creating new service instance")
            cls.__instance = QObject.__new__(cls)
        else:
            print("Returning existing service instance")

        return cls.__instance

    def do_something(self):
        print("Do something")
        self.something_changed.emit()
```

**Classes.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from Service import Service

class Parent(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._service = Service()
        self._service.something_changed.connect(self._something_changed)
        print("Init Parent: " + self.__class__.__name__)

    def _something_changed(self):
        print("Parent - _something_changed: " + self.__class__.__name__)


class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Init Child1: " + self.__class__.__name__)

    def _something_changed(self):
        print("Child1 - _something_changed: " + self.__class__.__name__)


class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Init Child2: " + self.__class__.__name__)

    def _something_changed(self):
        print("Child2 - _something_changed: " + self.__class__.__name__)
```

**main.py**

```
from Classes import Child1, Child2
from Service import Service

if __name__ == "__main__":
    service = Service()

    child1 = Child1()
    child2 = Child2()

    service.do_something()
```

**And the resulting output:**

```
Creating new service instance
Returning existing service instance
Init Parent: Child1
Init Child1: Child1
Returning existing service instance
Init Parent: Child2
Init Child2: Child2
Do something
Child2 - _something_changed: Child2
```

What I expected and what I also tried to achieve is to run the "_something_changed"-function from both children when the signal was emitted.

Additional node:

When I comment the the `child2 = Child2()` initialization, child1's "_something_changed"-function is called, so the connection must be established.

Thanks

Comment: Overriding `__new__` can be problematic with PyQt classses. If you get rid of it and use a factory function that returns a module global instead, your example will work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @ekhumoro. I replaced the `__new__` method with a static get_instance method based on [this](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1098129) gist and it worked!